# Stack View Generated Constraints Breaking

Tags: ios, constraints, uistackview

I have a view controller with several stack views nested inside of each other. The storyboard looks fine, everything lines up perfectly. But at run time I get the following output.

```
2016-02-15 15:08:32.330 WVSurvey[97389:14208896] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbb917aa030 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50]   (Names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fbb915bc420 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb91488be0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIStackView:0x7fbb9390ced0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fbb915bc420 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb914b2950 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIStackView:0x7fbb9390ced0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb93a2af30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIStackView:0x7fbb915bc420(1024)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb914b2950 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIStackView:0x7fbb9390ced0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-15 15:08:32.330 WVSurvey[97389:14208896] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbb91709db0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbb917aa030 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50]   (Names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fbb915bc420 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbb93912770 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb9390c080(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbb93912720 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb9390c080.bottom == UIStackView:0x7fbb915bc420.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb914e6aa0 'UISV-spacing' V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb9390c080]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb93a2af30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIStackView:0x7fbb915bc420(1024)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb914e6aa0 'UISV-spacing' V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb9390c080]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-15 15:08:32.331 WVSurvey[97389:14208896] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fbb91709db0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb914e6af0 'UISV-hiding' V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb914e6af0 'UISV-hiding' V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb93901a50(0)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Also, this is what the storyboard looks like, versus runtime.

[image: Storyboard]
[image: Runtime]

There shouldn't be a bunch of black, but other than that everything **seems** to look correct. Can't fix the black background, either.

My question is how can I track down and fix the conflicting constraints if I'm not even making them? I even tried deleting **all** of the constraints and still get this output.

Comment: Try to change your controller in the storyboard to freeform and chose a smaller size, and you should get the errors in the storyboard